# IllegalStateException thrown sometimes resulting in app crash when searching for location (Google Maps)

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map activity which uses Google Maps where it searches for the location and outputs the address of it. My problem is, it works most of the time, but sometimes when searching for the location, it crashes. This is my logcat:

```
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     ... 11 more
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     at com.example.shareity.MapAct.geoLocate(MapAct.java:111)
05-22 08:49:03.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4007):     ... 14 more
```

This is my code. Can someone please point out why this is happening?

```
public class Map2 extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final float DEFAULTZOOM = 15;
    public static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

    //Button btnSelect; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectLoc);

        if(servicesOK()){

            setContentView(R.layout.map2);
            if(initMap()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectLoc);

                /*btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent back = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EventCreateN.class);
                        startActivity(back);
                    }
                });*/

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Map not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        else{
            setContentView(R.layout.map2);
        }
    }

    public boolean servicesOK(){
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            return true;
        }
        else if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)){
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean initMap(){
        if (mMap == null){
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = 
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
        }
            return (mMap != null);
    }

    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom){
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat,lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException{
        hideSoftKeyboard(v);

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String location = et.getText().toString();

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
            Address add = list.get(0);
            //String locality = add.getLocality();
            String add1 = add.getAddressLine(1);
            //String add2 = add.getAddressLine(2);
            //String add3 = add.getAddressLine(3);
            String add0 = add.getAddressLine(0);
            //String add4 = add.getAddressLine(4);

            Toast.makeText(this, add0 + "," + add1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            double lat = add.getLatitude();
            double lng = add.getLongitude();

            gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULTZOOM);
            String message = "Current Location \nLongitude: "+lng+"\nLatitude: "+lat;
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final Intent yourIntent = new Intent(Map2.this, EventCreateN.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            yourIntent.putExtra("key",add0 + "," + add1);
            yourIntent.putExtra("key2", lng+","+lat);

            //set delay
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {


                    // Do something after 5s = 5000ms

                    startActivity(yourIntent);
                }
            }, 5000);

            /*
            //send double
            b.putDouble("key", lat);
            yourIntent.putExtras(b);*/

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: put ur code in try and catch..

Comment: First check network availability and also put a check for location not equal to null and then proceed

Comment: @DJphy I have a feeling that the crash happens when the network is quite slow. How exactly can I handle this matter?

Comment: in that case give a timeout..

Comment: a time out for the `geoLocate()` function?

Comment: Even with  a 2G data u will get the required data about location within 5-7 sec...I was supposed to do this check for my company..And also for their comfortability i implemented a timeout.

Comment: Yeah, u start ur getLocate using another thread, And make the main thread join with atmost time included so that either the success or the timeout will happen. If timeout happen location will be null so u can print network slow(like that)

Comment: @DJphy, if you can see, I'm setting the layout after calling to `servicesOK()` function. Should I add a network check there?

Comment: private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
  
     ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
     return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
     
 }

Comment: U can try the above code to check if the device is connected to any active networks... u can load map before itself, the thing is that when u request a new location to be fetched u do a check..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String, int):

`getFromLocationName(...)` throws an `IllegalArgumentException`if `locationName` is null and an `IOException` if the network is unavailable or any other I/O problem occurs.

In your LogCat, we can see that `getFromLocationName(...)` is throwing an IOException:

> java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server

So there you have it: the problem is that either the network is unavailable or another I/O problem occurred.

Comment: I have handled the null location matter, by displaying a message saying the location is null. How can I handle the IO Exception?

Comment: You can always use a try/catch block, and handle the IOException in the catch block.